# <unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.12.sdk'

Tags: xcode, macos-high-sierra

I'm on macOS 10.13.3 and I created a new fresh macOS project with Xcode(9.2). Without any custom code I changed the Base SDK from 10.13 (which is default) to 10.12 in the Build Settings of the target. When I build it I get this error:

> :0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.12.sdk'

I also changed the version (Base SDK) to 10.2 for `macOS Deployment Target`. I also changed the two locations for the Project Settings. But it does not compile. I always get this error.

I can't imagine that swift is not backward compatible. Even to change the swift version from 4 to 3.2 has no effect. Is there really no way to compile this new fresh project for SDK 10.12 or even 10.10? Any help is highly appreciated.

**What I did before:**
To be able to change the version of the BaseSDK within Xcode,
I downloaded the SDK's from here: https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs. I edited the info.plist file in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer` There I deleted this two lines of code:

```
<key>MinimumSDKVersion</key>
<string>10.11</string>
```

Comment: Normally, I leave the base SDK as whatever Xcode defaults (Latest macOS) and then change the deployment target to what I want.  Does that work for your situation?

Comment: Changing the deployment target higher then 10.9 works fine. But there another reason why I want to change the Base SDK. Its because I want to add a library and when I do this I get a bad Linker warning saying: `warning: object file (...) was built for newer OSX version (10.13) than being linked (10.9)` That's why I have to change the Base SDK and that does not work.